# How do I use an HTML escape character in the label of a Struts2 text field?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, struts2, escaping, html-escape-characters

I'm attempting to use a lowercase Greek mu (μ) in my Struts2 text field's label, as such:

```
<s:textfield name="measurement" label="Time Measurement (&mu;s)" />
```

However, I'm seeing "Time Measurement (&mu;s)" instead of "Time Measurement (μs)". Struts2 seems to be helping me out by escaping my escaped label! I'd rather not resort to a) using the UTF-8 character which file systems, servers or browsers may not respect, or b) using Struts2 i18n properties files which I don't need elsewhere and seem like overkill for just solving this problem. Is there any simple way to just turn off escaping of the label, or an escape character to indicate to not escape the ampersand? If it's not clear, I'm using JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just write it like `µ` in label attribute.

```
<s:textfield name="measurement" label="Time Measurement (µs)" />
```

You can put escaped characters inside `<s:textfield>` tag:

```
<s:textfield name="measurement">
  Time Measurement (&mu;s)
</s:textfield>
```

Comment: That does work in my dev environment, but using the UTF-8 character is one of the things I'm specifically trying to avoid. It means my editor, the server and the user's browser must all support UTF-8, or else "weird stuff happens." I guess that's less and less of an issue these days, so maybe I'm just being a curmudgeon.

Comment: ... So it is. Well played, sir! It doesn't really answer the larger question if I was attempting to use an HTML escape code outside of ISO 8859-1, but it does fix my immediate problem.

Comment: Wait a sec... Where in that Wikipedia article do you see mu?

Comment: @Xylo04: Codepage layout -> 181.

Comment: @Xylo04: Answer to large question. :)